# Push notification for separate Angular 2 Client and Laravel PHP Backend

Tags: php, laravel, angular, push-notification

Currently, I'm developing an e-commerce App that serves as a portal for multiple games so they can purchase goods from the portal with their in-game currencies, they have to do a game-portal binding before they could convert or buy things with their in-game currencies.

The binding process starts when a client requests to bind to certain game and receive a series of Code from backend server, and client would enter the code into their game (IOS / Android), if they succeed, it pushes notification to web browser for updates.

As for the Push notification, other than using a poll, what do you think i should use ?

- Backend : PHP Laravel (web service)
- Frontend : Angular 2
- Server : Fedora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use WebSockets. Laravel has [event broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting) which can be used to send events to something a long the lines of a [socket.io](http://socket.io) server. In the browser that can be connected to the websocket server and wait for events to be pushed across in real time.

[Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51) is a step by step tutorial for Laravel and [socket.io](http://socket.io)

You could also use a 3rd party push notification service and connect Laravel to send events to that. Something like [pusher](https://pusher.com)